# edge browser require page refreshing to view the uploaded file using javascript in aurelia framework

Tags: javascript, file, upload, frameworks, aurelia

Iam trying  to upload a **new pdf** file in **edge** browser using **javascript** but it require **page refresh** to view the newly uploaded file.it works fine in chrome.I tried **setTimeout** but it **wont work**

```
upload(){
    var pdfViewerObject = document.getElementById("myPdfObject");
    pdfViewerObject.removeAttribute("data");
        this.profileApi = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+":"+window.location.port+"/demo url /"+this.userId+"/profile?loadTime=" + new Date().getTime();
        pdfViewerObject.setAttribute("data", this.profileApi);
    }
```

Comment: whats the connection to `aurelia`? (its in the tags)

Comment: iam using aurelia framework for doing my project.